# Transmission 4r44e Wire harness replacement

Tags: electrical, ford, automatic-transmission, ranger

Im trying to figure out which wires should i use to replace these.

[image: 4r44e internal wire harness]

keep in mind these cost roughly $ 140 new, currently I cant afford that. used go for $ 50 dlls

Im mostly interested in looking for good replacement wires so I can repair it my self.

Harness complete  [image: new harness]

Comment: Are you asking what type of wire you should use or how to repair it?  Shopping questions along the line of "where can I buy this" are off topic.

Comment: Im aaking what type of wires i should use to replace them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are called "twisted core" wires (as opposed to "solid core" wires). Get something of the same gauge and you should be fine. Any store that sells wires will have a tool to measure wire gauges, just bring your old one to measure. Make sure the insulator is of similar thickness (or thicker).

Comment: Also mention that the wires are for automotive use.  The insulation needs to be oil/chemical resistant and safe for high temperatures.